# Which unsupported characters exist for the dotenv file?

Tags: fortrabbit

I'm trying to store a Facebook API Access-Token in Fortrabbit's environment variables. (.env and app secret)

But I get the message:

> Unsupported characters or malformed nested ENV vars.

I think the problem might be, that my token contains a `|` character.

- Is there a list of unsupported characters?
- Is there a way to escape this character?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a list of unsupported characters?

Here is the regex for the validation:

`/^[\p{L}\p{N}\ _\-\+=\.,:;\?!@~%&\*\(\)\[\]\{\}<>\/\\#]+$/u`

> Is there a way to escape this character?

We recommend to base64 encode the value and decode it before usage.